# Configure syslog file in Raspbian Stretch Lite

Tags: syslog

I am working with a Raspberry Pi Zero W and Raspbian OS and use the log file `syslog` which is located in `/var/log/syslog/` to track specific events. My problem is, that the `syslog`file is overwritten after some time (after about 1 day in my case). How can I configure the `syslog` file to keep the data for a specific time. Like for 1 month or so? Is that possible?

Comment: Configure [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate).

Comment: @IporSircer Could you please provide a minimal example how to set up a maximum size for the `syslog` file before a new one is created? That would help me really a lot.

Comment: `man logrotate`